# how to write this test in playwright: if element text as int is > 0 test pass else test fail

Tags: e2e-testing, assertion, playwright

I am trying to see if a number being displayed on a page is greater than 0 or not.
If it is I need the test to pass
if not I need the test to fail

The code I have so far

```
test("searching for 0100t should show a out of pocket expense", async()=>{
    let surgicalCentersCost = await page.$$eval('.chart-inner-label-cost >> nth=0')
    let hospitalOutpatientCost = await page.$$eval('.chart-inner-label-cost >> nth=1')
    surgicalCentersCost = surgicalCentersCost.replace('$','');
    hospitalOutpatientCost = hospitalOutpatientCost.replace('$','');
    surgicalCentersCost = parseInt(surgicalCentersCost);
    hospitalOutpatientCost = parseInt(hospitalOutpatientCost)
    expect(surgicalCentersCost) // <-- what happens here?

  })
```

essentially Id like an if statement that looks at `surgicalCentersCost` and `hospitalOutpatientCost` and if both are > 0 signal test pass otherwise signal test fail

I know we can do things like this in cypress but the company I am working for insits on playwright. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: What does `.chart-inner-label-cost >> nth=0` resolve to? you may need to replace the code with something like `let surgicalCentersCost = await page.locator('.chart-inner-label-cost >> nth=0').innerText()`, hard to tell without seeing the page. As for the expect conditions you need  `expect(surgicalCentersCost > 0).toBeTruthy(); expect(hospitalOutpatientCost > 0).toBeTruthy(); `

Answer (score 0):

Im about to test this but it looks like regex is the way to go. Observe the last 2 lines.

```
test("searching for 0100t should show a out of pocket expense", async()=>{
    let surgicalCentersCost = await page.$$eval('.chart-inner-label-cost >> nth=0')
    let hospitalOutpatientCost = await page.$$eval('.chart-inner-label-cost >> nth=1')
    surgicalCentersCost = surgicalCentersCost.replace('$','');
    hospitalOutpatientCost = hospitalOutpatientCost.replace('$','');
    surgicalCentersCost = surgicalCentersCost.replace(',','');
    hospitalOutpatientCost = hospitalOutpatientCost.replace(',','');
    surgicalCentersCost = parseInt(surgicalCentersCost);
    hospitalOutpatientCost = parseInt(hospitalOutpatientCost)
    await expect(surgicalCentersCost).toHaveValue(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/)
    await expect(hospitalOutpatientCost).toHaveValue(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/)

  })
```